# Collapsing Toolbar with RecyclerView fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I would want to collapse my toolbar from a fragment. The problem is that I am using TabLayout inside of BottomNavigationView's fragment. The RecyclerView is in every fragment of the TabLayout and the Toolbar is in the main activity with the BottomNavigationView. So my layout hierarchy looks like this:

MainActivity: Toolbar, BottomNavigationView

 ->Fragment 1: TabLayout

 --->Fragment: RecyclerView

 --->Fragment: RecyclerView

 --->Fragment: RecyclerView

 ->Fragment 2

 ->Fragment 3

Is it possible to collapse the toolbar like this?

Here is what I've tried:

 main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/topDisplay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding= "false"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The included toolbar_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="App title"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The TabLayout's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coordinator"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the RecyclerView's fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/video_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```